# Javafx : Activate a tooltip with a button

Tags: button, javafx, tooltip

I'm using JavaFx for a little app and a want to display a tooltip on a textArea when the user is clicking on a "help" button.

No problem for linking a tootltip to my textArea, but no way to activate it when the user click on the button. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: With what event did you try to display it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability to display a Tooltip on demand requires a resolution of [RT-19538 Customizable visibility timing for Tooltip](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19538), which is not implemented in JavaFX 2.2.

As a workaround, you could try any of the possible strategies below:

1. Displaying your Tooltip data in a [ContextMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html) instead.  With a ContextMenu, you have complete control over when it is shown.
2. You could create a custom [PopupControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html) for your required functionality.
3. You could replace the default TooltipSkin with a custom implemented skin which allows you to control when the Tooltip is displayed.
4. You could implement RT-19538 and provide a patch to the [Tooltip](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.java) and [TooltipSkin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TooltipSkin.java) to the [openjfx](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) project.

3rd party libraries such as [Jide's JavaFX Beta Release](https://www.jidesoft.com/blog/2013/06/11/highlights-of-the-jidefx-beta-release-3-of-3/) provide special classes like Decorator utilities, IntelliHints and ShapedPopups which *might* be useful in your case.

Answer (score 15):

This is what you are looking for:

```
final Button helpButton = new Button("Help");
helpButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler()
{
    public void handle(Event arg0)
    {
        showTooltip(stage, helpButton, "test tool tip", null);
    }
});

public static void showTooltip(Stage owner, Control control, String tooltipText,
    ImageView tooltipGraphic)
{
    Point2D p = control.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);

    final Tooltip customTooltip = new Tooltip();
    customTooltip.setText(tooltipText);

    control.setTooltip(customTooltip);
    customTooltip.setAutoHide(true);

    customTooltip.show(owner, p.getX()
        + control.getScene().getX() + control.getScene().getWindow().getX(), p.getY()
        + control.getScene().getY() + control.getScene().getWindow().getY());

}
```

Just pass the button as an input instead of control.

Answer (score 2):

The following show a tooltip over `control`.
If `control`has a `Tooltip` assigned to, this tooltip is not chnaged.

```
public static void showOneTimeTooltip(Control control, String tooltipText) {

    Point2D p = control.localToScreen(5 , 5);

    final Tooltip customTooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipText);
    customTooltip.setAutoHide(false);
    customTooltip.show(control,p.getX(),p.getY());

    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
    pt.setOnFinished(e->{
        customTooltip.hide();
    });
    pt.play();
}
```