# Form validator message

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm looking for form validator similar to these examples:

[image]

or

[image]

Is this custom JavaFX component or this can be done using standard JavaFX?

Is there any example how I can create form validator similar to these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javaFX - Field validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825436/javafx-field-validation)

Comment: You can make such custom components using Javafx standard components. I am not aware of any such custom component available, but you can make one, as per you need !

Comment: For your second option (for a popup on the field) see: [ControlsFX PopOver](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#popover)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just to give you a kick start, here is a small example with using [ContextMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html). May be `ContextMenu` is not an ideal Control for this scenario and you are free to replace it with [Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html), [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) etc. Keep the `TextField` and `Label` inside a HBox (with Label being hidden initially) and the HBox into the `GridPane`. Or, you may use any other method all together !

*You can design the validation messages/controls with CSS !*

Just to add (May be you are aware of this):

**Functionally**, it depends on you, **when** do you want to trigger the validation and **what** should your validation condition be. In my example, I am checking for **empty Textfields** and I have triggered the validation on the **click** of the **Sign in** button. You can trigger the validation, under **similar scenario** or, on **removing focus** from any **TextField** or, some other scenario !

*There are various approaches to what you are looking for and javafx being so rich in UI controls and design, it completely depends on your creativity !*

**ValidationDemo.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ValidationDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Validation Demo");
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter(loadLoginScreen());
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 700, 500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                ValidationDemo.class.getResource("context.css")
                        .toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private GridPane loadLoginScreen() {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        final TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label pw = new Label("Password:");
        grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

        final PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

        Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        // Context Menu for error messages
        final ContextMenu usernameValidator = new ContextMenu();
        usernameValidator.setAutoHide(false);
        final ContextMenu passValidator = new ContextMenu();
        passValidator.setAutoHide(false);

        // Action on button press
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // Clearing message if any
                actiontarget.setText("");

                // Checking if the userTextField is empty
                if (userTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                    usernameValidator.getItems().clear();
                    usernameValidator.getItems().add(
                            new MenuItem("Please enter username"));
                    usernameValidator.show(userTextField, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
                }
                // Checking if the pwBox is empty
                if (pwBox.getText().equals("")) {
                    passValidator.getItems().clear();
                    passValidator.getItems().add(
                            new MenuItem("Please enter Password"));
                    passValidator.show(pwBox, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
                }
                // If both of the above textFields have values
                if (!pwBox.getText().equals("")
                        && !userTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                    actiontarget.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                    actiontarget.setText("Welcome");
                }
            }
        });

        userTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                            Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                        if (newPropertyValue) {
                            // Clearing message if any
                            actiontarget.setText("");
                            // Hiding the error message
                            usernameValidator.hide();
                        }
                    }
                });

        pwBox.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                if (newPropertyValue) {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText("");
                    // Hiding the error message
                    passValidator.hide();
                }
            }
        });
        return grid;
    }

}
```

**context.css**

```
.root {
  -fx-background-color: cornsilk; 
  -fx-padding: 10;
}

.context-menu {
  -fx-background-color: #006699;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
  -fx-padding: 0;
}

.context-menu:hover {
  -fx-background-color: #006699;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.menu-item .label {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.menu-item:focused .label {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Comment: I found one issue here. When I click the button without entering any text I see the validation messages. During this time when I open another software I see the validation messages over Firefox for example. How I can hide the messages when I hide the JavaFX application?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue on javafx 2.2 (jdk 1.7.0_51) on my mac

Comment: I'm using latest Java 8. Maybe it's a bug in Java 8?

Comment: can you show me some example with ToolTip for example? Context menu is not very suitable for me.

Comment: A ToolTip might not be a good idea, since customizable visiblity timing is still an open issue for ToolTip. For more info visit https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19538. You can use Hidden Label's as suggested or pop-up controls. For similar things http://stackoverflow.com/a/17411781/1759128

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a library called JFoenix that has JavaFX nodes with material design, it also implements some utilities like a TextField validator, but for their own material textfield which is `JFXTextField`, and that's how it looks:

[image]

you can also add an image to it like an alert icon if you want.

Here is how you would do it:

```
JFXTextField validationField = new JFXTextField();
RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
validator.setMessage("Input Required");
validationField.getValidators().add(validator);
validationField.focusedProperty().addListener((o,oldVal,newVal)->{
    if(!newVal) validationField.validate();
});
```

Here the `RequiredFieldValidator` checks whether the textfield is empty, other validators are `RegexValidator`,`DoubleValidator`, `IntegerValidator` and `NumberValidator`.

source: [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/documentation.html#inputfields)