# error message displays if the user enters a character that isn't an integer

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing this program for a class i am in and i have been able to create this code. I know that it is very messy and i apologize. I need to find a way to have the program prevent the user from entering anything besides and integer. if i had a way for it to check i would be able to make a new stage appear myself. if there are any ideas i would be happy to hear them. Again I am not asking anyone to make the app for me i just need a way to check if there are characters other than integers and do something in that case. like a for else loop. Thanks in advance. (this is the first time i have ever used JavaFX so go easy:/

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.*;
public class Lab9Test extends Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//launch it all
launch(args);
    }
 @Override //create the grids scenes stages needed to run the program
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     final Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
     Label Label1 = new Label ("ERROR! You cannot divide by zero!");
    Button Okay = new Button("Okay!"); 
    GridPane GPane2 = new GridPane();
     GPane2.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
     GPane2.setVgap(10);
        GPane2.setHgap(-32);
        GPane2.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(GPane2, 222,300);
        GridPane.setConstraints(Okay,4,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(Label1,0,2);


    VBox root = new VBox();

    dialogStage.setScene(scene2);

     dialogStage.getIcons().add(new 

     GPane2.getChildren().addAll(Label1, Okay);
     Okay.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                dialogStage.close();    

            }
        });


     primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Arithmatic");

        GridPane GPane = new GridPane();

        GPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        GPane.setVgap(10);
        GPane.setHgap(-75);
        GPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(GPane, 325, 250);


        Button add = new Button();
        add.setText("+");
        Button multiply = new Button();
        multiply.setText("*");
        Button divide = new Button();
        divide.setText("/");
        Button subtract = new Button();
        subtract.setText("-");
        Button percent = new Button();
        percent.setText("%");
        Button clear = new Button();
        clear.setText("CLEAR");



        Text scenetitle = new Text("Enter two numbers and select an operation.");
        Text SecondNumber = new Text("Second Number:");
        Text FirstNumber = new Text("First Number:");
        Text Result = new Text("Result:");
        //create text fields
        final TextField TFFirstNumber = new TextField();
        final TextField TFSecondNumber = new TextField();
        final TextField TFResult = new TextField();

        //change position on grid
        GridPane.setConstraints(FirstNumber,0,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(SecondNumber,0,2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(Result,0,3);
        GridPane.setConstraints(add,0,4);
        GridPane.setConstraints(multiply,0,5);
        GridPane.setConstraints(percent,0,6);
        GridPane.setConstraints(divide,1,5);
        GridPane.setConstraints(subtract,1,4);
        GridPane.setConstraints(clear,1,6);
        GridPane.setConstraints(scenetitle,0,0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(TFFirstNumber,1,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(TFSecondNumber,1,2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(TFResult,1,3);

        GPane.getChildren().addAll(TFResult,TFFirstNumber,TFSecondNumber,add,FirstNumber,SecondNumber,Result,subtract,multiply,divide,percent,clear,scenetitle);
        //change size and alter the text fields 
        add.setMaxWidth(150);
        subtract.setMaxWidth(150);
        clear.setMaxWidth(150);
        divide.setMaxWidth(150);
        percent.setMaxWidth(150);
        multiply.setMaxWidth(150);
        TFFirstNumber.setMaxWidth(150);
        TFSecondNumber.setMaxWidth(150);
        TFResult.setMaxWidth(150);
        TFResult.setEditable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new 
        primaryStage.show();
        //give all of the buttons a purpose in life
        add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){

            Integer value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
            Integer value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());
            Integer r = value1 + value2;
            TFResult.setText(r.toString());
            }
        });
        subtract.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){

                Integer value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
                Integer value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());
                Integer r = value1 - value2;
                TFResult.setText(r.toString());
            }
        });
        multiply.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                Integer value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
                Integer value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());
                Integer r = value1 * value2;
                TFResult.setText(r.toString());
            }
        });
        divide.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                Integer value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
                Integer value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());

                if(value2==0){
                    dialogStage.show();
                }
                else{
                    Integer r = value1 / value2;
                    TFResult.setText(r.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        percent.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                Integer value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
                Integer value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());
                Integer r = value1 % value2;
                TFResult.setText(r.toString());
            }
        });
        clear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            TFFirstNumber.clear();
            TFSecondNumber.clear();
            TFResult.clear();
            }
        });
 }





    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Input Validation Textfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935279/javafx-input-validation-textfield)

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate offers a good solution, but there is another way:

You could wrap the parsing of the integers in something like this:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    Integer value1 = 0;
    Integer value2 = 0;
    try {
        value1  = Integer.valueOf(TFFirstNumber.getText());
        value2  = Integer.valueOf(TFSecondNumber.getText());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Wrong input value: needs to be an integer");
        return; // i.e. do mothing more
    }
    Integer r = value1 + value2;
    TFResult.setText(r.toString());
}
```