# Javafx Text Area User Input

Tags: java, javafx

I need to check user input in realtime. So when the user has entered more than for example 40 characters, he will be sent to the next line. I tried to use getText method in onKeyReleased method, but when the user hold the key, it can enter more than 40 characters. Sorry, maybe the explanation is not good enough.

Comment: I recommend making it into a property and then add a listener to the property, then whenever it changes you can check if the length of input is > 40, then you can jump them to the next line. Hope that helps

Comment: how to access the field method from fxml?

Comment: Here's something that might help you that i saw. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30935675/8029396

Comment: There may be an onTextChanged method

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160899/value-change-listener-for-javafxs-textfield) and check the length of the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are looking is something like that:

```
/* [Code...] */

 @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        firstField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.length() > 40)
                secondField.requestFocus();
        });
    }

/* [Code..] */
```

Need to do the changes on the Controller class.
As Sendrick suggested on the link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160899/value-change-listener-for-javafxs-textfield).