# JavaFx mark input control as mandatory

Tags: java, javafx

I started learning JavaFx, so I decided to do a little practical project to prove my knowledge. As a result of that I come to the situation, where I search for a possibility to easily disable e.g: a button until, other previous input controls (e.g: textfield) are correctly filled.

I already know event listeners in JavaFx or in Java at all, but im not sure about how to implement an event listener, which solves my problem.

I searched for a solution, but I didn't find one, so hopefully there's someone out there which has an idea how to solve it.

So far,
Daniel

Comment: You need to define an event listener for the button that checks all input fields on click and if one field isnt correct shows an error
It the problem implementing an event listener or the checking of the input fields?

Comment: Maybe you find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935279/javafx-input-validation-textfield

Comment: Disabling a submission button is not an especially good user interface design.  Users won’t intuitively know what to do in order to enable it.  Instead, consider either displaying an error dialog when that button is pressed, or making specific validation messages appear next to each field with incorrect/missing input, which update whenever the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

EventListener's aren't the correct way to handle disabling buttons and other controls based on the status of other nodes on the screen.  You should use Bindings.  Here's a sample screen with two TextFields.  The top one needs to just be non empty, and the bottom one needs to have a numeric value in it for the button to be enabled.  For those who dislike disabled buttons, I've added a Text with an error message at the bottom, and its visibility is linked to the enabled/disabled status of the button:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ButtonDisable extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField1 = new TextField();
        TextField textField2 = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        Text errorText = new Text("Field 1 must have a value, Field 2 must have a numeric value");
        button.disableProperty()
              .bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> checkTextfields(textField1.getText(), textField2.getText()),
                                                  textField1.textProperty(),
                                                  textField2.textProperty()));
        errorText.visibleProperty().bind(button.disabledProperty());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(10, textField1, textField2, button, errorText), 400, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean checkTextfields(String text1, String text2) {
        return (text1.isEmpty() || !isNumeric(text2));
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nit-pick: don't use parseDouble for convertion - it'll fail in most Locales :)