# Javafx How to Show Tooltip on a button when click on another button?

Tags: java, button, javafx, tooltip

Javafx How to Show Tooltip on a button when click on another button?
should I use Tooltip.show()?

```
Button bt1 = new Button();
Button bt2 = new Button("I am going to show tooltip when a lick on bt1 ");
bt1.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
    //to dos
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. how to handle here?
Help Appreciated!
Is this too simple? why no one's glad to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405688/javafx-activate-a-tooltip-with-a-button

Comment: Still don't understand...